# Aligning with layout-align

Tags: angular-material

I have buttons (to achieve ripple effect) which have an image, then text.

I want to the buttons full width, which they are and the images and text to start left, but they're center aligned as seen below:

[image]

This is what I'm trying but it's as if `layout-align` doesn't apply to buttons but surely it should?

```
<md-list role="list">
  <md-item ng-repeat="x in courses" layout="column">
    <a href="#" layout="column">
      <md-button layout="row" layout-align="start center">
          <img ng-src="/assets/course_images/{{x.image_name}}" class="course--image" fallback-src="/assets/img/intro-bg-lite.jpg">
            {{x.course_name}}, {{x.course_address}}
      </md-button>
    </a>
  </md-item>
</md-list>
```

CSS for image:

```
.course--image {
  border-radius: 60px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin: 4px 16px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Material has md-list & md-cards which seem to be better options. You can choose one you like.

1.) **md-list** (seems to go with yr problem).

```
<md-list role="list">
  <md-list-item ng-repeat="x in courses">
       <img ng-src="/assets/course_images/{{x.image_name}}" class="md-avatar" fallback-src="/assets/img/intro-bg-lite.jpg" ng-click=''>         
      <div class="md-list-item-text">          
        <md-button class="md-primary" ng-click="">
          {{x.course_name}}, {{x.course_address}}
        </md-button>
      </div>
   <md-divider ng-hide='$last'></md-divider>
  </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

2.) **md-cards**

```
<md-content>
 <md-card ng-repeat="x in courses">
  <md-card-content layout="row" layout-align="start center" layout-padding>
    <img ng-src="/assets/course_images/{{x.image_name}}" 
      class="md-avatar" alt=""
         ng-click=''>
      <md-button class="md-primary" ng-click=''>
          {{x.course_name}}, {{x.course_address}}
      </md-button>       
   </md-card-content>
 </md-card>
</md-content>
```